# code for Shell command in android

Tags: android

```
  Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
  OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
  os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
  os.flush();
  os.close();
  sh.waitFor();
```

This is code for shell command for taking screenshot below, but through it just give partial output  , i dont know why

```
  (adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png)
```

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear. I suggest you edit it to be specific about what is happening vs. what you expect to happen, otherwise I would expect the question to get closed. Incidentally, instead of spawning `su` and then feeding it `/system/bin/screencap ...`, you should spawn `su -c /system/bin/screencap...`.

Comment: @mah i just need the entire screenshot which is getting through that shell conmmand . but the code only gives partial output 10% of screenshot, i need code for entire screenshot

Comment: it sounds like your question is "`/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png` is not performing a full screenshot" -- if this is the case, you need some serious work with the title and body of your question as it has nothing to do with starting a command, rather only to do with a (potentially faulty) tool on your system.

Comment: @mah But that shell command works perfectly,what changes are you looking for?that code gives partial output

Comment: I see; that wasn't clear :)   My only suggestion is that you replace the exec() call with `.exec("su -c /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png");` and remove the OutputStream code. I don't know that it will help but it will at least simplify your code without harm.

Comment: @mah i got it without anychanges i dont know how , its the same above code thanks for ur suggestions